# Converse.js Message Archiving not working

Tags: xmpp, openfire, converse.js

I am currently using the ConverseJS library in order to connect to the XMPP server and it is working pitch perfect. The one problem I am facing is that I want the chat history and in XMPP there is a function to fetch the message. I am using the Openfire Server and using the Monitoring plugin's latest version as well.

When I open any chat window then the spinner runs and then no old messages are shown. In the console log it gives the following error:

```
 iq type="error" id="334" to="user1@mydomain.com/458">
 <error type="cancel" code="501">
 <feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
 </error>
 </iq>
```

So can anyone tell me any possible solution regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it. In Openfire, there is setting where you can allow to fetch the chat history. Its value was 0 and it was stopping from fetching the history. But as I entered 7, then i started sending the history.

Hope this will help others as well.

Comment: Hello. Can you please let me know what setting is this in openfire server? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure install plugin `Monitoring Service` and then server restart.
also make sure open fire version 3.10.* for Monitoring Service 4.6 .
follow this link https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/57111, it may be work for you.
it is work for me.

Comment: I am already using Monitoring Service Plugin and the version is 4.7 and for the Openfire the version is 3.10.3 and I have already gone though the link and every possible solution in order to get the answer. You said it worked for you. Can you please tell me the steps that you performed? It may help me out. Thanks.